# Add suffix to Atom editor to show code right

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Contao CMS and the template files got the suffix .html5.
Now when I open this file I want that the code is displayed like PHP code.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [custom file type](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-language-recognition) in your Atom configuration (`config.cson`, can be opened from the Atom menu).

[image]

*Screenshot: Atom menu on macOS*

**Example:**

```
core:
  customFileTypes:
    "source.php": [
      "html5"
    ]
```

Remember that this is a CoffeeScript Object Notation file, so correct indentation matters. If there is an existing `core` key, add the `customFileType` to it.

Here's another example with some more context:

```
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
    themes: [
      "one-light-ui"
      "one-dark-syntax"
    ]
    customFileTypes:
      "source.php": [
        "html5"
      ]
```

If you prefer JSON, you can convert the same file to JSON and name it accordingly to `config.json`.